# PDF of Random Variable $\sin\alpha \cdot \cos\beta$ with $\alpha,\beta$ uniform

Tags: trigonometry, random-variables

As part of a bigger problem, I want to compute the probability density $f_Z(z)$ of 
$$Z = \sin\alpha \cdot \cos\beta$$ 
where $\alpha, \beta$ are random variables, independently and uniformly distributed over $[0,\pi/2]$. Looks quite simple, but I have a really hard time.

What I tried is writing it like $Z = X \cdot Y$ and compute $f_X(x)$, $f_Y(y)$ to then use the product distribution formula ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution ). The calculation went:

$$x = g(\alpha) = \sin\alpha, \ \ \ g^{-1}(x) = \arcsin x$$
$$\frac{d g^{-1}(x)}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
$$f_\alpha(g^{-1}(x)) = \frac{2}{\pi} \ \ \text{for} \ \ 0\leq x \leq 1$$
$$f_X(x) = f_\alpha(g^{-1}(x)) \cdot \left| \frac{d g^{-1}(x)}{dx} \right| = \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \ \ \text{for} \ \ 0\leq x \leq 1$$

Similarly,
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \ \ \text{for} \ \ 0\leq y \leq 1$$

and the product distribution then gives:

\begin{align*}
f_Z(z) 
&= \int_\mathbb{R} f_X(x) f_Y(z/x) \frac{1}{|x|}dx\\
&= \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)^2 \cdot \int_z^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(x^2-z^2)}}
\end{align*}

While that integral doesn't look too hard (just like the initial problem), even Mathematica fails to give me any answer. Is this problem really that hard or am I missing something?

Comment: I get "an" answer for the indefinite integral on W|A with the input `integrate [(1-x^2)(x^2-k^2)]^(-1/2)dx`, screenshot here http://i.imgur.com/mY4f0z0.png The elliptic integral means you won't be able to get an exact solution for every z in terms of the usual functions, but there should be some special cases.